# Elixir CSV Issue

Tags: csv, elixir

UPDATE:

CSV now looks like this:

`01|Data1\n02|Data2\n01|Data3`

and no errors have thrown.

However the IO inspect prints an email array / list?

`[]`

so I not sure if that is something to do with my code?

ORIGINAL POST:

I am getting the following error:

`(NimbleCSV.ParseError) unexpected escape character " in "01|Data1\",\"02|Data2\",\"01|Data3"`

The CSV file is as follows:

`01|Data1","02|Data2","01|Data3`

But I have also tried: (thinking I was missing the start / end char in the data)

`"01|Data1","02|Data2","01|Data3"`

This is the Elixir code I have:

```
NimbleCSV.define(MyParser, separator: "|", escape: "\"")

File.stream!("data.csv")
|> NimbleCSV.RFC4180.parse_stream()
|> Stream.map(fn [code, data] ->
  %{code: code, data: data}
end)
|> Enum.to_list()
|> IO.inspect()
```

The NimbleCSV is at the top of my file, outside the start of the module.

Comment: I would expect your CSV file to be more like: `01|Data1\n02|Data2\n01|Data3`; no quotes, newlines to separate individual lines.

Comment: It looks like your CSV file is improperly formatted -- in which case you'd have trouble no matter what language/package you used.  Can you include a sample of the first several lines?  E.g. paste the output of `head -3 your.csv` and include it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NimbleCSV expects the first line to be a header:

```elixir
NimbleCSV.define(MyParser, separator: "|")

"""
code|data
01|Data1
02|Data2
01|Data3
"""
|> MyParser.parse_string()
```

Output:

```elixir
[["01", "Data1"], ["02", "Data2"], ["01", "Data3"]]
```

Comment: many thanks for your help, this works as you have give it. However it was given me an error with the ```File.steam``` but seems to work file with ```File.read```

Comment: If you use `File.stream`, you need to also use `MyParser.parse_stream` (not `parse_string`, as I used here).